# Opening Twitter with URL isn't working // SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have this Link (previously I was using button, same result), it is to my profile, my main question is, why it is not working, I added "twitter" Queried URL Schemes, and Twitter is installed, I also testing it on the real device.
Console is outputting this info:

> [default] Failed to open URL twitter:///user?screen_name=nikolomoec: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=244, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:fileHandle:options:completionHandler:]}

Here is my link:

```
Link(destination: URL(string: "twitter://user?screen_name=nikolomoec")!) {
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .frame(height: geo.size.height / 5)
                            .foregroundStyle(.bar)
                            .translucentStroke(10)
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text("Twitter DMs")
                                .font(.title3.bold())
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Image("Twitter")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                    }
                }
```

And my secondary question is, what is the link to again, redirect users to twitter app, but not to my profile, to posting section with pasted link, something like this:
[image]

Comment: I don't think that kind of links are supported, except mailto and tel

Comment: Twitter isn’t Twitter anymore I would check the api if it was working before.

Comment: and how to check it? Sorry, I am not knowing much about apis

Comment: Google Twitter api. See if it is even still available. I think one of things musk was doing was closing the api I don’t know if it is even still available.